# After quotation, is putting "spoke" instead of "said" still grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, direct-speech

For example:

> "She's upstairs," said Tom.

What if *spoke* is put in the place of *said*? Meaning:

> "She's upstairs," spoke Tom.

I haven't seen anything like that in books or anywhere really, but is that correct, grammar-wise? If *said* was replaced with *thought* or *wrote*, it'd still be correct, but I'm uncertain regarding *spoke*.

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said%20Tom%2C%20spoke%20Tom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaid%20Tom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoke%20Tom%3B%2Cc0) show barely any usage for *spoke*, and Google itself doesn't show particularly any reliable sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, they aren't directly interchangeable.**

Say/said is (usually) a transitive verb; that is, it takes an object. Tom *said "Hello"* or *said "Goodbye"* or *said "She's upstairs"*, but he never just *said*.

On the other hand, speak/spoke can be intransitive or transitive. It often doesn't need an object - it is entirely acceptable to say '*Tom spoke*' without elaborating on what was spoken - and when it does take one, it is usually an abstract description, not a direct quote. Tom might *speak English*, or *speak the truth* or *speak volumes*, but he is unlikely to ever *speak "go away"* or *speak "what are you doing?"*.

Comment: Thanks. And perhaps it should be "transitive" instead of "transative"?

Comment: Quick followup question: would it be right to put "mocked Tom" or "taunted Tom"?

Comment: No. The object for mock or taunt is generally the *target*, not the thing being said: *Tom mocked Sally*, rather than *Tom mocked "Ha Ha"*. (And the most common word order is subject-verb-object, so 'mocked Tom' risks implying that he is *being* mocked rather than doing the mocking)